# Grand Central Dispatch: How do I wait for the queue of blocks to complete?

Tags: ios5, grand-central-dispatch

In iOS I have an app where I need to wait for the currently running blocks on a GCD queue to complete. I was under the impression that this line of code will do just that:

`dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{});`

I got this tip from here:

http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/27/a-simple-job-queue-with-grand-central-dispatch/

As I understand it, this line of code will block subsequence execution until all tasks running on the global queue complete. In my code this does not appear to be happening. Can someone please suggest an approach that will do this?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dispatch_sync()` *trick* will only work for serial queues, which is what that tutorial is showing. The `dispatch_get_global_queue()` returns a concurrent queue, see [it's documentation note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_global_queue):

> Blocks submitted to these global concurrent queues may be executed concurrently with respect to each other.

To deal with a global concurrent queue you should use a group where you submit your blocks, also mentioned on that tutorial, and wait for the whole group with `dispatch_group_wait()`.

Comment: Bingo. That was indeed the issues. Switching to a sequential FIFO queue now has this working. Thanks so much Grzegorz.

Comment: Doesn't work if you're already on the queue, as it will deadlock.